# What is the correct English word for a person who always suspects other people without any valid reason?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What is the correct English word for a person who always suspects other people (like colleagues, wife, and, so on), whose habit is to suspect people around him, without any valid reason?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the definitions here, for example - http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/suspect?s=t ?

Comment: A neurotic obsessive paranoid, or if you prefer an ex-spouse.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127220/terminology-what-is-the-exact-word-to-describe-being-skeptical-of-something-s/127221#127221

Answer (score 5):

> **Paranoid**: a person suffering from ***paranoia*** (a baseless or excessive suspicion of the motives of others.)

Answer (score 0):

the correct word to be used, depending on context, is paranoid